# Something like INDEX MATCH for google sheets that will return the header

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, formula, lookup

If I have reference cells that say 58 and 137, I would want it to return 1.

The first column is the first refence point and the rest is the second reference point, but i need it to "round" the value of the reference cell to the next number.

So for ROW 56, anything =<87 would return 0 and 88-140 would return 1 ect

```
    0   1   3   4   
56  87  140 179 186
57  91  145 185 192
58  94  150 192 199
59  97  155 199 206
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B9, SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:D7&"×"&A1:D1, ROW(A2:A7)=A9)), "×"), 2, 1), A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Ill try these out and see if i can understand how they work while I am at it!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution:

```
=min(index(
  if(B62<=
   sort(flatten(filter(A56:D59,row(A56:D59)=A62)),row(A56:D59),),
   sort(flatten(A55:D55),flatten(column(A55:D55)),)
  )  
 )
)
```

[image]